# can't pickle the object module from pool.map

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to parallelize loop with pair of numbers and some other fixed data. That is, I'm iterating pair of numbers like (1,2), (6,4), (4,3)... with other fixed dataset.

```
def myfunc(list of iterates, list of various datasets)
    doing stuff

if __name__ == '__main__':
    read_data(a lot)
    iterates = [[1,2], [3,8], [7,9], [12,5]] # means nothing

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    partial_myfunc = partial(myfunc, list of various datasets=some_data)
    results = pool.map(partial_myfunc, iterates)
```

myfunc is doing stuff with two inputs, list of iterates, list of various datasets.

'list of iterates' consists of like this [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]...],
'list of various datasets' contains various types of dataset like [dates, float, dataframe,... etc] but it's fixed.

And when I run the main program mentioned above, python says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "path/main.py", line 117, in <module>
results = pool.map(partial_myfunc, iterates)
File "lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 266, in map
return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
File "lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 644, in get
raise self._value
File "lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 424, in _handle_tasks
put(task)
File "lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 206, in send
self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
File "lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle module objects
```

Is there anybody can tell what's going on? I really need some help guys.

Answer (score 0):

could you adjust your code for the threading to be the following please:

```
...
max_threads = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

...
#create pool with max_threads - feel free to do max_threads-1 so your device is still usable
p = multiprocessing.Pool(max_threads)

results = p.map(partial_myfunc, iterates)
```

also are you using python 2 or 3? The more information you proivde the easier it is to figure out :) 
Let me know if it makes any difference!

Comment: Actually in my code, i'm using           "num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()             pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_cores)" and python ver is 3.6.